# How to push array to array? (two dimensional array javascript codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter

Sorry I'm a javascript beginner.
I have a problem with my data.
I hope someone can give me solution (with the documentation of js or answer in here).
I have arrays

```
var array1 = ["you","they","them","he","she","it"];
var array2 = ["we","us","me","I"];
```

and I have an array to save that arrays

```
var data = [][]; //I don't know how to write.
```

how to save that array1 and array2 in data?
and how to print that data?
thanks.

Comment: It's unclear how the two arrays should relate to each other in `data` - can you show what sort of structure you might be looking for?

Comment: What's your expected output when you push your arrays in data?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the two? Or are you drying to achieve 2-D array?

Comment: Yeah I'm not super sure this would be the right structure... Do you want to fill it with a vectorial product of the two vectors?

Comment: I want to push the data in my controller with ajax. And I want to condense it into one variable.

Comment: Is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var array1 = ["you","they","them","he","she","it"];
var array2 = ["we","us","me","I"];

var mergedArray = [];
mergedArray.push(array1);
mergedArray.push(array2);
console.log(mergedArray); //To access the merged array
console.log(mergedArray[0]); //To access first array
console.log(mergedArray[0][0]); //To access element inside first array
```

Comment: thank you sir. you solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Start off by creating an array

```
var arr = [];
```

and simply push your other arrays to it

```
arr.push(["you","they","them","he","she","it"]);
arr.push(["we","us","me","I"]);
```

You can retrieve individual items like so

```
var youVar = arr[0][0]; // has value "you"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll try it!